# Find the number of arrangements

Tags: combinatorics

There are 9 people and they have to sit around a round table, find the number of arrangements so that in each arrangement no person has the same neighbour ?

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing this is asking for a Hamilton decompostion of $K_9$, i.e., a decomposition of $K_9$ into $C_9$'s.  This can be achieved using the Walecki decomposition.  As in my answer here [Partition edges of complete graph into paths of distinct length](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2130583/91818) it can be achieved by:

[image: Decomposition of K_9 into C_9]

Here's another example, drawn to show how people sit around the table:

[image: Decomposition of K_9 into C_9]